# External library having troubles with android.R in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using an external library in my Android project which used to work fine. But after doing a clean to the project, the external library started to mark some errors in, for example, the android.R.attr.ordering and other android SDK related properties:

```
private static final int[] AnimatorSet = new int[] {
    /* 0 */ android.R.attr.ordering,
};
```

All this errors seem to be some issue with the SDK configurations, but i had already checked for Window>Preferences>Android and i am using the correct SDK location. Any idea why this might be happening? Thanks.

Comment: look to see if an import statement was added for something with the .R occasionally this will be added and cause it to use the wrong .R Very odd thing to say and I'm not sure how to word it right but just try removing the import statement that contains it if its there

Comment: Thanks, but my issue was caused because in the android's properties of the project (in this case the external library) the Project Build Target was changed for a different target instead of the Google APIs

Answer (score 0):

Notice that android.R.attr have been added in >> [API 11](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#ordering) <<.

Check android:minSdkVersion to point it to API 11 in your manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your.package.name.here"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
...
```

Also, right click your project and choose the correct API

[image]